# Vertex paint dirty vertex colors highlighting the wrong places

Tags: texturing

I tried adding dirty vertex colors to my sniper scope but it didn't seem to like sharp edges, The image of it is down below , any help would be appreciated. Thanks :D

[image]

Comment: There is probably not enough geometry or detail. Also check your normals.

Comment: You could adjust settings a bit.. E.g. set Highlight angle a bit down and Dirt angle a bit up. Also Vertex paint relies on topology, so the problem could be with it.